# Read SQl table row by row and update a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to read a table row ID by row ID and update a some cell,

If

row id is 123 and get the row id (123), Search in the folder for one image from many images image that ID is named with a Text EX -  `Name_123_AA.JPG` and Take the Full Image name and update the Name cell in current row ID (123).

Comment: which Data Approach you are using, i mean Entity Framework, Linq, Store Procedures ?

Comment: i'm using Store Procedures to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a specific file name you are looking for you can simply check for the existance of it in the directory:

```
int rowID = 123;

string fileName = "Text Ex - Name_" + rowID.ToString() + "_AA.jpg";
if (System.IO.File.Exists("YourDirectory\\" + fileName))
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE YourTable SET FilePath = @FilePath WHERE RowID = @RowID", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", fileName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowID", rowID);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If you need to do a search, the [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method allows using a search patter, so you might have something like:

```
string searchPattern = "*" + rowID.ToString() + "*"; // adapt as required
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("YourDirectory", searchPattern);

if (files.length > 0)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE YourTable SET FilePath = @FilePath WHERE RowID = @RowID", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", Path.GetFileName(Getfiles[0]));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowID", rowID);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case got a problem when file name split, Name_ string is may be some other thing. how to use with various names

string_111_string.jpg

int ID = 111;
string fileName = "Name_" + ID.ToString() + "_AA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that, first get your id from Database and than

```
DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Your Folder Name/"));
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            foreach (FileInfo finfo in dirinfo.GetFiles())
            {
                files.Add(finfo.FullName);
            }
            //Check with ID 

            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    if (item.Contains(yourId from database))
                    {
                        //just update this FileName(URL) in database
                    }
                }
            }
```